# How to not repeat yourself by finding all tables in HTML

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

In my HTML code, I have 8 tables. Here is how I am trying to get them:

```
url ="http://www.uefa.com/worldcup/season=2014/standings/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
table = soup.find("table")
```

This piece of code gives me only the first one table. Now the action takes place:

```
rows = table.findAll('tr')
data = [[td.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for td in tr.findAll("td")] for tr in rows]
head = [[th.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for th in tr.findAll("th")] for tr in rows]

for i in data:
    if i:
        flag = i[1][:3] + ".png"
        i.insert(1, Datas(i, "http://img.uefa.com/imgml/flags/18x18/" + flag))

return render(request, 'Titles.html', {"data": data})
```

After action ends, I'm wondering how to start extracting second table with the same variables? Of course I could add more variables like `data1`, `data2`, `head1`, `head2` and so on. However I don't want to repeat myself.
So maybe you can help me and find the better way to do it?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783579/find-all-tables-in-html-using-beautifulsoup)

Comment: I already looked there. However, I get this error: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

tables = soup.find_all('table') # this returns 8 tables
print len(tables)

for table in tables:
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        print tr.text
        print
```

If you try that code, you can see you get the content out of each table,

Comment: The if-statement is not needed.

Comment: @DarinDouglass you are right, just a way to show that he should work with tables that only contain `tr's`

Comment: Before, it showed only first table. Now it shows only fast.. How to repair my HTML in order to get all tables?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza That is a valid reason.

Comment: I found out the way. Thanks

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis on the updated code example is the complete working example.